# Angular 4 @HostBinding bind to style prop

Tags: angular

i am trying to bind to style prop of an ele with directive

```js
import {Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, HostListener, HostBinding} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    "selector":"[high-light-direc]"
})
export class HighlightDirec implements OnInit{
    @HostBinding('style') style:{backgroundColor:string};
    constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef){}
    ngOnInit(){
        
    }
    @HostListener('mouseenter') x(){
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
    @HostListener('mouseleave') y(){
        this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
    }
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <p high-light-direc>
      {{toShow}}
    </p>
  </div>
```

and when i try to assign a value to backgroundColor prop i get this ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined .

so how to assign value to backgroundColor prop which is in Binded style obj .

Comment: Well, you've never initialized the `style`field, so it's undefined. The syntax for initializing a variable is `= someValue`.

Comment: i did that already and i got WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value [object Object] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Comment: @HostBinding('style.background-color') style:{backgroundColor:string};

Comment: still the same result

Comment: The error doesn't happen here (and trying to access an uninitialized variable can't possibly be a correct fix). You can indeed use the colution of Osama, except the style attribute must just be a string (since it is bound to `the background-color style, which is a string.

Comment: what i am trying to do is to pass object of styles to Binded style prop is that possible or i have to Bind to every prop separately

Comment: @andrewsaeed It's possible to send sanitized css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take a look at the code:

[Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-hostbinding-bind-to-style-prop)

> Explanation:

1. Use Style Sanitizer `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle`
2. You have to send sanitized CSS instead: `@HostBinding('style') style: SafeStyle;`
3. Then set the values this way:

   ```
   @HostListener('mouseenter') x() {
      this.style = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("background-
      color: lime");
   }
   @HostListener('mouseleave') y() {
     this.style = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("background-color: transparent");
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you a lot , i have used `this.style = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("background-color: transparent;color:black;");` now i can pass all css in one line by sending sanitized css